# Translating 1GB of text to English

Tags: google-translate, language-translation, machine-translation

I'm looking for a language translation API/solution that would fit my use case.

My use case is the following:

- The data is 1 GB of free unstructured text written mostly in the world's common languages (French, Spanish, German, Russian, Korean). The language of each piece of text is known.
- We can assume the text is grammatically correct and consists of complete sentences, but contains some uncommon words such as chemical compound names.
- The text has to be translated to English.
- The solution must be at least 10x cheaper than Google Translate which charges $20 per 1M characters.
- I would be willing to trade some of the Google's quality for cost-effectiveness. Google, Yahoo, Microsoft, Yandex, Online-Translator.com are all good enough, just too expensive.

I've got a 16 CPU machine at my disposal so offline translation is an option too.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please consult the help pages to get an idea what kind of question is [on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Questions asking to recommend a tool or a software library are explicitly off-topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your volumes, Machine Translation prices range from $3 to $25 per 1M symbols (with some outliers like ModernMT which costs $eu per 1000 words).

[image: MT Price Comparison]

If you want to trade off a little bit of quality, you may pick what we call "Optimal engines" - one which are within top 5% by performance but have the lowest price.

[image: Optimal general-purpose MT engines]

You may find more details in [our Machine Translation report from July 2018](https://www.slideshare.net/KonstantinSavenkov/state-of-the-machine-translation-by-intento-july-2018).

Then, you need to know which engines support your language pairs and deal with their APIs, request limits and quotas.

You may use [Intento](http://inten.to) API to [get a list of engines for your language pairs](https://github.com/intento/intento-api/blob/master/ai.text.translate.md#filtering-providers-by-capabilities).
Then, you may use this API in [the async mode](https://github.com/intento/intento-api#async-mode), then Intento takes care of all the limits. However I am not sure it will deal with 1G file, but you're welcome to try.

To avoid tinkering with the API requests, I would suggest using [the CLI](https://github.com/intento/intento-nodejs/tree/master/samples/cli).